# Why is it that the second code works while the first one doesnt?

Tags: c++, arrays, reference

I am aware that in order for the first program to work I need to pass a and b by reference, however, in the second code, I get the desired output even though I pass the array by value in all the given function. Why is that? If I can pass arrays by value why not the variables in the first program?

I have tried looking for answers on StackOverflow and other websites but couldn't get a particular answer that would answer my question.

```
    //FIRST PROGRAM 
    #include<iostream>

    using namespace std;

    int swap (int a, int b) 
    { 
       int temp; 
       temp = a; 
       a = b; 
       b = temp; 

    }

    int main() {

        int x=5,y=6;
        swap(x,y);
        cout<<x<<y;
    }
```

```
    //SECOND PROGRAM

    #include<iostream> 

    /*Function to return max sum such that no two elements 
     are adjacent */
    int FindMaxSum(int arr[], int n) 
    { 
      int incl = arr[0]; 
      int excl = 0; 
      int excl_new; 
      int i; 

      for (i = 1; i < n; i++) 
      { 
         /* current max excluding i */
         excl_new = (incl > excl)? incl: excl; 

         /* current max including i */
         incl = excl + arr[i]; 
         excl = excl_new; 
      } 

       /* return max of incl and excl */
       return ((incl > excl)? incl : excl); 
    } 

    /* Driver program to test above function */
    int main() 
    { 
      int arr[] = {5,200,199,2}; 
      int n = sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0]); 
      cout<<FindMaxSum(arr, n); 
      return 0; 
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

When you pass `arr` in the second case, you're not passing the whole array *by value*, but rather you are passing the pointer to the first element by value.

You can modify the array in the function via pointer arithmetic and pointer deference. Clearly you can't do that in the first snippet.

C is being helpful in allowing you to use the `int arr[]` notation in the function parameter list, but really it's `int* arr`. The `arr` at the calling site *decays* to a pointer type.

This pointer decay happens in most operations involving arrays. `sizeof` is an important exception which is why you can use the idiom `sizeof(arr) / sizeof(arr[0])` in the calling function. But note that this will give you, in general, a different result in `FindMaxSum` due to the pointer decay.

Comment: Thank you very much this clears things a lot, also does it mean that it's good programming practice to use &variable or *variable every time you pass a variable in a function or can you get away with passing by value most of the time??

Comment: @AdityaMishra: I always pass by value unless I want to modify the variable in the function.

Answer (score 0):

This comes down to the fact that C-style arrays are treated as pointers.
`void foo(int[])` and `void foo(int*)` are equivalent declarations in C.